# Return a value from Popup Window

Tags: android, popup

I have popup window class like the following.

```
public class Popup extends PopupWindow {

Context context;
EditText et_bankname, et_banknumber;
String bank_name, account_number;

public Popup(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx);
    context = ctx;

    setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bank_details, null));
    setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    View popupView = getContentView();
    setFocusable(true);
    Button btn_close = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popupClose);
    Button btn_submit = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popupSave);
    et_bankname = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.bank_name);
    et_banknumber = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.bankacc_no);
    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            bank_name = et_bankname.getText().toString();
            account_number = et_banknumber.getText().toString();
            if (!bank_name.equals("") && !account_number.equals("")) {      
                Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(context,bank_name + " "+account_number , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 100);
                t1.show();                  
                dismiss();                              
            } else {
                Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Please provide valid details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 100);
                t1.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void show(View v) {
    showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
}
```

I will access this popup in my activity by

```
Popup popup = new Popup(getBaseContext());
popup.show(arg1);
```

This works perfectly. But I want to know when this popup window gets dismissed. for this purpose now I am using `Thread` concept like following.

```
if (isPopupShowing) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (isPopupShowing) {
                    if (!popup.isShowing()) {
                        isPopupShowing = false;
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                loadDSP(type);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

But this thread will run continuesly until the popup window gets dismissed. So I feel it is better to replace this solution by any other way.

What I want? 
Just intimate to my activity like "popup is closed" when popup is dismissed.

Why I am use this way?
I will use this popup window in three activty. That is why I am create a separate class for popup window.

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try a combination of wait(in UI) and notify(in pop up) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PopupWindow already has its own dismiss listener, just use it as follows

```
Popup popup = new Popup(getBaseContext());
popup.show(arg1);
```

Change that to

```
Popup popup = new Popup(getBaseContext());

popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                // Do your action
            }
        });

popup.show(arg1);
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**
I hadn't noticed you were extending a PopupWindow, which already has this implemented as shown in @Jayabal's answer. Anyway this is how you would do it if the PopupWindow didn't already have it's own onDismissListener.

Simply create your own OnDismissListener Interface.

```
public interface onDismissListener{

    public void onDismiss();

}
```

Add a reference to a Listener in the PopUp class and a setter.

```
OnDismissListener listener;

public void setOnDismissListener(OnDismissListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Then in your Activity

```
Popup popup = new Popup(getBaseContext());
popup.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){

    public void onDismiss(){
        //do what you need to here
    }
});
popup.show(arg1);
```

This pattern should be familiar to you, its used everywhere in Android.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I don't know why. Anyway thank you. Added +1 for show me to create own `OnDismissListener`.